# MATLAB: Object Array Property Assignment with Deal

Tags: arrays, matlab, oop

I have a class constructor that takes multiple numeric arrays of the same size and creates an object array of the same size. In the constructor, I am trying to use `deal` to assign data from each input array to a single index of the object array's only property:

```
classdef myClass
    properties
        data
    end
    methods
        function obj = myClass(varargin)
            nArg = length(varargin);
            for iArg = 1:nArg
                dataArg = num2cell(varargin{iArg});
                [obj.data(iArg)] = deal(dataArg{:});
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error from deal: `The number of outputs should match the number of inputs.`

I believe that this is probably occurring because I haven't preallocated the object array before the `for` loop in the constructor, e.g.:

```
szObj = size(varargin{1});
cellSzObj = num2cell(szObj);
obj(cellSzObj{:}) = myClass.empty;
```

However, for various reasons, I want to be able to make this assignment without preallocating the object array.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can't you write `obj.data = varargin;`?

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for. The error I mentioned only occurs if I provide the constructor with arrays larger than 1x1, but this works just the way I want it to... `>> v = myClass(1, 2, 3)` creates `v.data` equal to `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: Can you provide a simple input and the expected output?

Comment: What I would like is for `>> v = myClass([1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6])` to create a 1x2 array of `myClass` objects, where `v(1).data` equals `[1, 2, 3]` and `v(2).data` equals `[4, 5, 6]`.

Comment: Your desired output indicates that you want your object constructor to instantiate multiple copies of itself, which doesn't really make sense. It would probably be a better idea to make a static method of your class with a simple loop that batch instantiates an array of your objects.